# UITextView setEnabled: causes the retain count to increment?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, retaincount

I have a UITextView which has its text sets from a local variable. Is it possible that after this:

```
[textView setEnabled:NO];
```

The retain count gets incremented by one?

**EDIT:**

The "problem", if it is a problem, is in the constructor of a small view:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSMutableArray *) {
  UITextView *myText;
  if ( ( self = [super init] ) ) {
    myText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:aRect];
    // retain count = 1;
    [myText setEnabled:NO]; // retain count 2
    [self addSubview:myText]; // retain count 3
    [myText release];  // retain count 2
  }
}
```

Now, I've "autoreleased" the text view, but I'm not sure if the memory is well managed (the post is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472560/memory-management-in-iphone)).

Comment: Retain counts, as a rule, are misleading and you shouldn't worry about them.  In your code snippet, what is likely happening is that some internal component is calling `[[myText retain] autorelease]` or something similar as part of its work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible?  Absolutely.

Do you care? Not a bit.   Not unless you overrode `setEnabled:` in a subclass and you are the one making the `retain` call.

If it is, it is an implementation detail in the frameworks.

---

Think about retain counts as deltas, not as absolute numbers.  The absolute value is meaningless.  Thus:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSMutableArray *) {
  UITextView *myText;
  if ( ( self = [super init] ) ) {
    myText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:aRect]; // rc +1
    [myText setEnabled:NO]; // rc change irrelevant
    [self addSubview:myText]; // rc change irrelevant
    [myText release];  // rc -1
  }
}
```

So, yes, you have managed memory correctly;  at the end of the scope of the `myText` local variable, all retains have been balanced by releases.

When you `addSubview:`, whether that method retains the object or makes a copy of it is an implementation detail that isn't relevant to memory management in this scope.   Obviously, that the subview maintains a reference and retains it is necessary for *its* purposes, but that is an implementation detail beyond the scope of this method's memory management!